# Find the error in Struts2 dropdown list program?

Tags: struts2

the three files are given for struts2.it is not giving the output.its giving
jasper exception.please find the errors

========================

```
updatedesig.jsp
```

=======================

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="p" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p:form action="count"method="post">
    <p:select name="country" list="countryList"  label="Select a country" />/*creating         list in jsp*/
    </p:form>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

========================

```
struts.xml
```

========================

```
<struts>

<package name="b" extends="struts-default">
<action name="count" class="b.Countr" >/*action class is Countr.java*/

  <result name="success">updatedesig.jsp</result>
 </action>
 </package>
 </struts>
```

============================

```
Countr.java
```

============================

```
 package b;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

 public class Countr extends ActionSupport/*class Countr*/
 {

 public ArrayList countrylist;
 String country;

 public  ArrayList getCountrylist()/*getting countrylist*/
 {
 return countrylist;
 }
 public void setCountrylist( ArrayList countrylist)/*setting countrylist*/
 {
 this.countrylist=countrylist;
 }
 public  String getCountry()/*getting country*/
 {
 return country;
 }
 public void setCountry( String country)/*setting country*/
 {
 this.country=country;
 }



 public String execute() 
 {
   countrylist = new ArrayList();/*creating the arraylist*/
   countrylist.add("1");
   countrylist.add("!");
   countrylist.add("1");
   return SUCCESS;

}

}
```

/*some parts of Glassfish server log  */

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'country': The requested list key 'countryList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:358)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:80)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Select.evaluateExtraParams(Select.java:105)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:856)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:510)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.updatedesig_jsp._jspx_meth_p_select_0(updatedesig_jsp.java:138)
    at org.apache.jsp.updatedesig_jsp._jspx_meth_p_form_0(updatedesig_jsp.java:107)
    at org.apache.jsp.updatedesig_jsp._jspService(updatedesig_jsp.java:68)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: have you tried what i have answered below? error says that the list you are trying to retrieve, framework is unable to find that in value-stack

Comment: i am not sir!!! at what point its giving you the exception/error?

Comment: i have given the exception above

Comment: i already mentioned that you have to get along with one appraoch.In your JSP you have mentioned list as `countryList` so in that case your action should have this property `countryList` but in your case you have defined the name of the property as `countrylist`.When you page is executing Struts2 is looking for a getter method name `getCountryList()` while in your case it is defined as `getCountrylist()` and hence framework is unable to find the required method.Solution it to either correct list name in your action class or in your JSP code.

Answer (score 2):

its always better to provide the error/exception being thrown by the system else its very hard for the other to tell anything.Moreover no one have that much time to write the programe in there system and see the error.

my first shot for possible error is

```
<p:select name="country" list="countryList"  label="Select a country" />
```

which means it will try to find the respected getter method `getCountryList()` in your action class but your action class have the following method

```
public  ArrayList getCountrylist()/*getting countrylist*/
 {
 return countrylist;
 }
```

either change the select to

```
  <p:select name="country" list="countrylist"  label="Select a country" />
```

or do the required correction in your action class.

Its always advisable to program to interface rather than implementation which will provide you more flexibility.

You can create `List` and initialize it with `ArrayList`.Here is what is working for me

### Action Class

```
List<String> countryList;

public List<String> getCountryList() {
        return countryList;
    }

public void setCountryList(List<String> countryList) {
        this.countryList = countryList;
}

countryList=new ArrayList<String>();
        countryList.add("1");
        countryList.add("!");
        countryList.add("1");
```

### JSP Class

```
<s:select name="country" list="countryList"  label="Select a country" />
```

### OutPut

[image]