# Getting error on selecting a value from a drop down select

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2, hql

I want to fetch a selected value from a drop down 'select' list of 'form' in a jsp page into a variable defined in the action class of the form, where 'select' drop down list is itself fetched dynamically from a column 'name' of database table 'Category' with the list 'categoryList' which is defined in some another action class.

After fetching the selected value (that is a name of Category) i want to fetch the primary key 'cid' of the table 'Category'. columns of Category are : id, name

After Retrieving the 'cid' of the category i want to fill this cid in the column 'cid' of   another table 'Question'.

I am using struts2 and hibernate.

My column is 'name' and table is 'Category'
I have made the mapping configuration and bean classes.

My code of action class where the list is generated :

```
public class FindCategory extends ActionSupport {

    private List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            this.categoryList = (List<Category>) session.createQuery("from Category").list();
            if (this.categoryList.isEmpty()) {
                this.addActionError("Sorry.. No category Available. Try again Later.!");
                return ERROR;
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.addActionError("Oops. An Error Encountered...!");
            return ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Category> getCategoryList() {
        return categoryList;
    }

    public void setCategoryList(List<Category> categoryList) {
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
    }
}
```

code in a 'form' of a jsp page :

```
<s:form action="okadddqs" method="post" cssClass="text">
                                <input type="hidden" name="email" value="goods.ramesh@gmail.com"/>
                                <s:select label="Select Category :" name="name" list="categoryList" listkey="name" listValue="name"/> //Here the list is generated
                                <s:textarea label="Your Question " cols="40" rows="5" name="body"/>
                                <s:textfield name="op1" label="Option 1 :"/>
                                <s:textfield name="op2" label="Option 2 :"/>
                                <s:textfield name="op3" label="Option 3 :"/>
                                <s:textfield name="op4" label="Option 4 :"/>
                                <s:textfield name="op5" label="Option 5 :"/>
                                <s:select label="Correct Option :" 
                                         name="opc"       
                                         list="#@java.util.LinkedHashMap@{'1':'One',
                                         '2':'Two','3':'Three','4':'Four','5':'Five'}"/>
                                <s:submit value="Update Daily Question"/>
                            </s:form>
```

My action to submit a new question class :

```
package com.rambo.action;

import beans.Category;
import beans.Question;
import beans.Users;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.hibernate.Session;

/**
 *
 * @author ROMO
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class NewQuestion extends ActionSupport {

    private String cname;

    private List<Category> cl = new ArrayList<Category>();


    public List<Category> getCl() {
        return cl;
    }

    public void setCl(List<Category> cl) {
        this.cl = cl;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        Session session = null;
        int c;
        //c store the cid of the selected Category name from drop down list.
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            cl = (List<Category>) session.createQuery("from Category c where c.name = '" + getName() + "'");
            if (!cl.isEmpty()) {
                c = cl.get(0).getCid();
            } else {
                this.addActionError("Oops. Sorry No Category Available.");
                session.close();
                return ERROR;
            }

            u = new Question();
            u.setCid(c);
            u.setCname(getName());
            session.save(u);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.addActionError("Oops. An Error Encountered...! Email address already registered. Try with your new email address.");
            session.close();
            return ERROR;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    @Override
    public void validate() {
        if ("".equals(getEmail()) || getEmail() == null ) {
            this.addActionError("All Fields are Compulsory to input..!");
        } else if (getEmail().indexOf("@") < 0 || getEmail().indexOf(",") > 0 || getEmail().indexOf(".") < 0) {
            this.addActionError("Please Input a valid email address.");
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping in Category.hbm.xml :

```
<property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
```

Getter and setter of the bean "Category.java":

```
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

My glassfish server shows error as :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'cname': The requested list key 'categoryList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]

root cause tag 'select', field 'list', name 'cname': The requested list key 'categoryList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

Can some one please point out what may b the error..?
    thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you submitting 'cname' from your select list, why not directly submit the 'cid'. It would reduce unnecessary code in your action class. Also the mentioned error is in the way youu are popu;ating the list not in this class

Comment: Actually i need to submit both 'cname' and also the correspoinding

Comment: But you are using `cname` in your class only to get back the corresponding `cid` from the same table `Category`.So, why dont you do that directly from the jsp and save 1 query. Are you using `canme` for any other purpose?

Comment: Actually i need to submit both 'cname' and also the correspoinding 'cid' to the new row of question table. (Each 'cname' has unique 'cid'). I have only the list of 'cname' on the form. And i want to picked up one 'cname' from list and then find its 'cid' then ultimately storing these in the new row of question table.

any other way or trick is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i have used cname because the general user remember the name more than any numeric id. So i have to display 'cname's on the list option.

Comment: You can display cname but submit cid using the `listKey` and `listValue` attributes.`<s:select label="Select Category :" name="cid" list="categoryList" listKey="id" listValue="name"/>`

Comment: that may be a good trick.. thanks alot.. and let me try now. I ll get back soon with the status of the problem a few minutes later.

Comment: OOOoops... the error is still the same.. help me out.

And with the trick, i ll be able to submit only cid, not the cname. I wish to submit both cid and cname to the new row of Question table.

is there any way to submit both cid and cname both together..?

Comment: you can use hidden field and javascript/jquery to submit both values. I will post an answer with the jquery code to do that. And that error is not related with this problem post the code where you are populating the list.Is the list `categoryList` is of type `Category` or is it a String list containing names only?

Comment: categoryList is of type String list. And this list is generated dynamically by fetching all the 'cnames' (one 'cname' for each row) from the rows of the Category table.
Plz plz plz avoid javascript. I am not allowed to use javascript here for some reasons. Only Jquery i can use.
Hoping to get some help.

Comment: If that is a string list only then you cannot submit both(id % name) values.Change that list type to `<Category>` so that it contains both the values and then use my answer which I am posting now. And still, it will not solve the exception, you have not posted your code in which you are populating the list.

Comment: Ok i changed the list type to Category as u said. And the code of the 'form' in jsp page and code in the action class in which i am populating list is made edited in my question above.

Comment: Can someone solve my aother problem..?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487435/how-to-setup-an-action-link-to-delete-the-row-from-the-table-loaded-from-the-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in comments, `categoryList` should be of type `Category` with getter/setter

```
List<Category> categoryList
```

then in your jsp

```
<s:select label="Select Category :"
       name="cid"
       id="cid"
       list="categoryList"
       listKey="id"
       listValue="name"
/>
```

Now declare a hidden field in your form to submit `cname` also, with `cid`

```
<s:hidden name="cname" id="cname"/>
```

**jQuery code**(as requested by you) to set `cname`

```
$("#cid").change(function(){
  $("#cname").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

You need to declare `cid` & `cname` variables(with getter/setter) in your `NewQuestion` action

Comment: @Rambo As per your edited question: where is the code where you are creating the `categoryList`? The exception is because of that part of code only.

Comment: Thanks.. I am just implementing the code u gave. I ll be back a few minutes later with status of the problem. And yes i have now edited my question with the code of action class 'FindCategory' that generate the list.

Comment: Sorry but the code is not actually working.. I am getting the 'cname' blank after submitting. What can be the probelem now..? I have already made the getter and setter of cname as well as of cid.

Comment: Are you sure the jquery part is working fine? try putting an alert statement(or breakpoint) in the jquery code to test whether its is setting the cname value or not. Are you able to submit the other(cid) value? Is the exception gone?

Comment: Yes cid is being submitted only the 'cname' remains blank. i am using jquery-1.7.2.js. is this the problem with version..? I tried to put an alert when cname is empty. But even i m not getting any altert. May b i dont know how to code the jquery. can u plz post the code of the whole content <script></script> tag.

thanks.

Comment: @ anu: I am waiting for your reply anu. Help me out. thanks.. and also solve my another problem (However these problems are exactly same) here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480674/how-to-automatically-copy-up-the-value-of-selected-option-of-dropdown-list-into

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuGw9/). Is that exception gone? Sorry it was saturday sp i couldnt reply earlier

Comment: Hi anu, Can u solve this problem too.. ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641662/doccookie-is-not-getting-saved-instantly

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your exception is coming from 'categoryList' code as the exception says.

see [Find the error in Struts2 dropdown list program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148980/find-the-error-in-struts2-dropdown-list-program) for more details . I am pretty sure you are on the same problem.

If not please post some more code, preferably the code that is suspected of having the problem (categoryList  variable and its getters and setters)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But the link you gave is showing the problem that drop down list is not having its options. 

For me. the drop down list having and showing its options properly. But it doesn't allow to sent back the selected value to another action class opon pressing submit button.

Can u plz point out the problem now..?

Comment: Please solve my another problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480674/how-to-automatically-copy-up-the-value-of-selected-option-of-dropdown-list-into